# Proof of a theorem regarding group homomorphisms and kernels

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for a proof of the following theorem:

"Let $H<G$ then $H\unlhd G$ $\iff$ there exists a group $K$ and a group homomorphism: $\phi : G \rightarrow K$ such that $ker(\phi) = H$

There is one on a french wikipedia page but I find it incomprehensible.

**Edit** I unfortunately don't know how to suppress questions from this site, I've found the answer I nee**

If anyone is interested, here's the link: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Kernel_is_Normal_Subgroup_of_Domain

Comment: Hint: Consider the homomorphism $G\to G/H$ (and kernels are always normal).

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that kernels and normal subgroups are essentially the same.

Let $H \le G$.  If $H \trianglelefteq G$, then we can form the quotient group $G/H$.  It can be shown that the natural homomorphism from $G$ to $G/H$ defined by $g \mapsto gH$ has kernel $H$.

Conversely, if $H \le G$ and $H$ is the kernel of some homomorphism from $G$ to another group $K$, then $H \trianglelefteq G$ because the kernel of a group homomorphism is always a normal subgroup of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The forward direction will be done by considering $K=G/H$ and for the converse part, kernel of a group homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.